# Lazy loading a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazy load genius' lyrics of a song at the end of my post. I discovered that jquery allows you to do that but my code isn't working. What am I doing wrong?
The page : https://soundsirius.digitalpress.blog/golden-rule-trust/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy@1.7.10/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy@1.7.10/jquery.lazy.plugins.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("div.rg_embed_link").lazyload({
effect : "fadeIn"
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the console/network tab for errors?  eg a 404 because you're missing `https:`?

Comment: I added https but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: That wasn't the question...